# Get Maximum Value from the mysql database in Php PDO and add one to it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want to fetch maximum value from column stud_id in Mysql database  and add 1 to it

for eg: if i get stud_id as 10 as maximum value i should add 1 to it and put back the result 11 into the new stud_id for next record but im get an error as "Array to string conversion"

```
stud_id
------
2
4
8
10
```

my code is

```
require 'Db.class.php';

$pdo=new DB();

$studid=$pdo->query("SELECT max(stud_id) maxcount FROM t_notes");

$version = $studid+1;

echo "$version";
```

Comment: Is there any reason `stud_id` is not auto-incrementing? Also, `$studid` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Why don't you just use `autoincreament`? Also, can you echo/print_r $studid and show the result?

Comment: @serakfalcon  :  i have used two primary keys in my table, so i cant auto increment the field Stud_id

Answer (score 0):

> PDO::query —  Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a PDOStatement object

The return value of `PDO::query()` is not a single value, but a record of those in a PDOStatement object. You have to fetch the result to work on it.

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php (See the examples on that doc page; They use Prepared Statements there – but `prepare` as well as `query` do both return a PDOStatement to work with, so the following lines in the example should help you out.)